# Start a CSS transition via JS does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to start a CSS transition, that changes the `background-color` and the dimension if a button is clicked. But there is a mistake in the code:

[js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v7AA7/148/)

jQuery

```
$(function() {

$('#change').click(function() {
    $('#box').addClass('change');
});
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="box" class="start"></div>

<div id="button">click</div>
```

CSS

```
.start{

height:100px;
width:100px;
background: black;
transition: all 2.0s linear;
-webkit-transition: all 0.8s linear;
-moz-transition: all 0.8s linear;
-ms-transition: all 0.8s linear;
-o-transition: all 0.8s linear;
}

.change{
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
background:yellow;
}

#button{
width: 80px;
height: 20px;
padding: 4px;
margin: 5px;
border:solid 1px black;
 background: grey;
cursor: pointer;
color: white;
}
```

Comment: you don't have element with id #change ))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The id of the button in the HTML & CSS (`#button`) is different from the id of the button in the JS (`#change`), that's why.

If you replace `#change` with `#button` in the JS, [**then it works**](http://jsfiddle.net/v7AA7/149/).

---

***Note***: When you list transition rules for various browsers, you don't need the `-ms-` one (IE10 supports transitions unprefixed and IE9 does not support them at all; the `-ms-` prefix was only needed for early IE10 previews) and **you should always put the unprefixed one last**. At this point, [all current versions of desktop browsers support transitions unprefixed](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions).

Answer (score 2):

Id of your `button` is `button`, not `change`.

Use `$('#button')` instead of `$('#change')`.

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/v7AA7/150/).

Answer (score 2):

It should be using #button,

```
$(function() {
    $('#button').click(function() {
        $('#box').addClass('change');
    });
});
```

as per your HTML

```
<div id="button">click</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qsAZQ/